# sql not adding data to the table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a windows form that I am trying to insert the data from a list box to a sql function I think it is passing in the data but somewhere in my function it is not writing the data to my table any ideas? when I step through that data it looks like it goes through the function until it to the if statement for it don't add the data to the table

```
'this is the data being passed in 
   DataConnection.addOrder(Date.Now, totalPizzas, totalDrinks, total)

Public Function addOrder(
    orderDate As Date, 
    orderPizzaTotals As Integer, 
    orderDrinkTotals As Integer, 
    orderPriceTotal As Decimal
) As Boolean
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
            "INSERT INTO dbo.[Order] (
                orderDate, orderPizzaTotals, orderDrinkTotals, orderPriceTotal) 
             VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');",
                orderDate, orderPizzaTotals, orderDrinkTotals,orderPriceTotal
            )
        cmd.Connection = con
        If cmd.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cmd.Connection.Open()
        Dim results = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If results > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no error?  It looks like you're trying to insert numeric data as strings in the SQL statement.

Comment: Modify the code to build the SQL statement and store it in a variable. Single step the code and examine the SQL generated, copy that to your DB editor window and execute the statement. Post any error message you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding any data to anything. You set up the query, run it and return true/false if it works, but you don't use the data from the query to populate anything. You either need some listener mechanism to fire when the query is run or update the grid directly with the data from the query.
B

Comment: You seem to be answering a different question to what is being asked. The OP is not asking about updating a Windows form, they are having problems inserting data in to a database table.